# Access parent dag context at subtag creation time in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to access at subdag creation time some xcom data from parent dag, I was searching to achieve this on internet but I didn't find something.

```
def test(task_id):
    logging.info(f' execution of task {task_id}')


def load_subdag(parent_dag_id, child_dag_id, args):
    dag_subdag = DAG(
        dag_id='{0}.{1}'.format(parent_dag_id, child_dag_id),
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval="@daily",
    )
    with dag_subdag:
        r = DummyOperator(task_id='random')

        for i in range(r.xcom_pull(task_ids='take_Ana', key='the_message', dag_id=parent_dag_id)):
            t = PythonOperator(
                task_id='load_subdag_{0}'.format(i),
                default_args=args,
                python_callable=print_context,
                op_kwargs={'task_id': 'load_subdag_{0}'.format(i)},
                dag=dag_subdag,
            )

    return dag_subdag

load_tasks = SubDagOperator(
        task_id='load_tasks',
        subdag=load_subdag(dag.dag_id,
                           'load_tasks', args),
        default_args=args,
    )
```

got this error with my code

```
1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 374, in process_file
airflow_1  |     m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
airflow_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
airflow_1  |     module = _load(spec)
airflow_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
airflow_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
airflow_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
airflow_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
airflow_1  |   File "/app/dags/airflow_dag_test.py", line 75, in <module>
airflow_1  |     'load_tasks', args),
airflow_1  |   File "/app/dags/airflow_dag_test.py", line 55, in load_subdag
airflow_1  |     for i in range(r.xcom_pull(task_ids='take_Ana', key='the_message', dag_id=parent_dag_id)):
airflow_1  | TypeError: xcom_pull() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

Comment: for those who visit this question of late, I'd suggest not overlook the **EDIT-2** part  of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746434/3679900) which offers a rather hacky yet viable solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is simple: you are missing the `context` argument required by [`xcom_pull()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3173) method. But you really can't just create `context` to pass into this method; it is a `Python` *dictionary* that `Airflow` passes to anchor methods like [`pre_execute()` and `execute()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2802) of `BaseOperator` (parent class of all `Operator`s).

In other words, `context` becomes available **only when `Operator` is actually executed, not during `DAG`-definition**. And it makes sense because in *taxanomy* of `Airflow`, `xcom`s are communication mechanism between `task`s in *realtime*: talking to each other while they are running.

---

But at the end of the day `Xcom`s, just like every other `Airflow` model, are persisted in *backend meta-db*. So of course you can directly retrieve it from there (obviously only the XCOMs of `task`s that had run in the past). While I don't have a *code-snippet*, you can have a look at [`cli.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L1166) where they've used the `SQLAlchemy` ORM to play with models and backend-db. Do understand that this would mean *a query being fired to your backend-db every time the `DAG`-definition file is parsed*, which happens rather quickly.

---

Useful links

- [How can one set a variable for use only during a certain dag_run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718229/54720571#comment96274031_54720571)
- [How to pull xcom value from other task instance in the same DAG run (not the most recent one)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668287/3679900)

---

**EDIT-1**

After looking at your *code-snippet*, I got alarmed. Assuming the value returned by `xcom_pull()` will keep changing frequently, the *number of `task`s in your `dag` will also keep changing*. This can lead to **unpredictable behaviours** (you should do a fair bit of research but I don't have a good feeling about it)

I'd suggest you revisit your entire task *workflow* and condense down to a design where the

- number of `task`s and
- structure of `DAG`
  are known ahead of time (at the time of *execution* of *dag-definition file*). You can of-course iterate over a `json` file / result of a `SQL` query (like the `SQLAlchemy` thing mentioned earlier) etc. to spawn your actual `task`s, but that file / db / whatever shouldn't be changing frequently.

---

Do understand that merely iterating over a list to generate `task`s is not problematic; what's NOT possible is to have structure of your `DAG` dependent on result of `upstream` `task`. For example you can't have n `task`s created in your `DAG` based on an *upstream task* calculating value of n at runtime.

---

So this is not possible

- [Airflow dynamic tasks at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48589633/3679900)
- [Is there a way to create dynamic workflows in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52296429/3679900)
- [Dynamically create list of tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45120122/3679900)

But this is possible (including what you are trying to achieve; even though the way you are doing it doesn't seem like a good idea)

- [Dynamically Generating DAGs in Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/)
- [Airflow DAG dynamic structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49114565/3679900)
- [etsy/boundary-layer](https://github.com/etsy/boundary-layer)
- [ajbosco/dag-factory](https://github.com/ajbosco/dag-factory)

---

**EDIT-2**

So as it turns out, generating tasks from output of upstream tasks is possible after all; although it requires significant amount of knowledge of internal workings of Airflow as well as a tinge of creativity.

- In fact unless you really understand it, I would strongly recommend to stay away from it.
- But for those who know no bounds here's the trick [Proper way to create Dynamic Workflows in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55896121/3679900)

**EDIT-3**

Airflow 2.3 added [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html). It can be used to iterate over a list and spin up a Task for each item.