# Airflow: How to get the return output of one task to set the dependencies of the downstream tasks to run?

Tags: airflow

We have a kubernetes pod operator that will spit out a python dictionary that will define which further downstream kubernetes pod operators to run along with their dependencies and the environment variables to pass into each operator.

How do I get this python dictionary object back into the executor's context (or is it worker's context?) so that airflow can spawn the downstream kubernetes operators?

I've looked at BranchOperator and TriggerDagRunOperator and XCOM push/pull and Variable.get and Variable.set, but nothing seems to quite work.

Answer (score 5):

> We have a kubernetes pod operator that will spit out a python
>   dictionary that will define which further downstream kubernetes pod
>   operators to run

This is possible, albeit not in the way you are trying. You'll have to **have all possible [`KubernetesPodOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator)s** already in your workflow and then **skip those that need not be run**.

An elegant way to do this would be to attach a [`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.ShortCircuitOperator) before each `KubernetesPodOperator` that reads the [`XCom`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms) (*dictionary*) published by the upstream `KubernetesPodOperator` and determines whether or not to continue with the downstream task.

**EDIT-1**

Actually a cleaner way would be to just [raise an `AirflowSkipException`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/62b21d747582d9d2b7cdcc34a326a8a060e2a8dd/airflow/example_dags/example_skip_dag.py#L32) within the task that you want to skip (rather than using a separate `ShortCircuitOperator` to do this)

---

> How do I get this python dictionary  ... so that airflow can spawn the
>   downstream kubernetes operators..

No. You can't **dynamically spawn new tasks** based on output of an *upstream task*.

Think of it this way: for `scheduler` it is imperative to know all the tasks (their `task_id`s, `trigger_rule`s, `priority_weight` etc) ahead of time so as to be able to execute them when the right time comes. If the tasks were to just keep coming up dynamically then `Airflow`'s scheduler would have to become akin to an *Operating System scheduler* (!). For more details read the **EDIT-1 part** of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746434/3679900) answer